# Flow - Validating Conditional Text Field Input

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a flow with a screen element. It has 3 picklist fields and, dependent on the input in these fields, a pair of conditionally visible text fields become available for input.

I want to validate the input in the text fields, so have set a rule in the Validate Input section to ensure an entry in the 'Licence Code' text field is always 20 characters long.

The rule works, but in debug it only displays when I 'Run Again'; the first time it looks as if the input validation has failed, then if I try again with the same picklist inputs the licence code entered on the previous pass is displayed with the error.

What is the best way to ensure the error is displayed and the flow stopped on the first pass to allow correction of the licence code field ?

Can I resolve this using the screen element only, or do I need to add a decision element ?

TIA

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula in the flow like this: `LEN({!Licence_Code_Input}) == 20` and use this formula as a resource inside the Validate Input/Formula section.